# Text with Divider in ChakraUI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I am using ChakraUI for one of my projects and I want to add a Text with Divider like this:
[image: Text with divider]

In ChakraUI, I could do this:
[image: my way of text with divider]

and code:

```
<Flex alignItems={"center"}>
    <Heading as="h4" size="lg">
          About the Department
    </Heading>
    <Divider border="4px" borderRadius={"2xl"} />
</Flex>
```

but I want to show the text in one line.

Although I could still use like this:

```
<Flex alignItems={"center"}>
    <Heading as="h4" size="lg">
          About&nbsp;the&nbsp;Department
    </Heading>
    <Divider border="4px" borderRadius={"2xl"} />
</Flex>
```

which will make the text in one line.

So I am wondering is there any way to show text in one line? as shown in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try add `whiteSpace: "nowrap"` to `Heading`.

A quick minimized demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-emztlh?file=src/App.js)

Example:

```
<Flex alignItems="center" gap={6}>
  <Heading as="h4" size="lg" sx={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
    About the Department
  </Heading>
  <Divider border="4px" borderRadius={"2xl"} />
</Flex>
```

An optional `gap={6}` is also added on `Flex` here to create a small gap between the `Heading` and `Divider`, but can be customized to fit the use case.